# Is there a way to replenish a keep's health?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

Your keeps get attacked a lot and have their health depleted. After returning and defending your keep is there a way to replenish its health without just allowing it to fall and winning it back (since this is obviously not even an option with the allied keep)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least for the Allied Base, the base starts recovering once EVERY enemy in the keep dies.

So if there is a single mook left, it won't heal back up.